# "Clever tricks" for using \outer macros

Tags: macros, tex-core

From *TeX by Topic,* p. 111:

> For certain applications, however, it is inconvenient that some of the plain macros are outer, in particular macros such as `\newskip`. One remedy is to redefine them, without the `outer' option, which is done for instance in LaTeX, **but cleverer tricks are possible.**

What are examples of such tricks for using `\outer` macros where they are not usually allowed?

Comment: 'Don't use them' ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As egreg said, the standard way is with `\csname`: as long as there is no `\outer` token at the time of the definition, you are safe.

So another possibility is, in a group, make the macro non-outer, define your macro, and then reset everything:

```
\begingroup
  \let\newdimen\relax
  \gdef\makedimenandgivevalue#1#2{%
    \newdimen#1%
    #1=#2\relax}
\endgroup
```

The problem with this version is that if you need to pass the `\outer` macro as argument to an auxiliary, you can't. A handier version is to define a non-outer wrapper to the `\outer` macro, then you can use it freely:

```
\edef\mynewdimen{\noexpand\newdimen}
%
\def\makedimenandgivevalue#1#2{%
  \mynewdimen#1%
  #1=#2\relax
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The standard trick is `\csname`:

```
\def\makedimenandgivevalue#1#2{%
  \csname newdimen\endcsname#1%
  #1=#2\relax
}
```

Or `\noexpand`:

```
\edef\myproclaim#1#2\endmyproclaim{\noexpand\proclaim #1. \ignorespaces #2\par}

\myproclaim{Theorem}
This is better syntax.
\endmyproclaim

\proclaim Theorem.
This is worse syntax.

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The famous `\cleartabs`, `\settabs` and `\+` macros from `plain.tex` show one such trick (TeXbook p. 354):

```latex
\let\+=\relax % in case this file (plain.tex) is being read in twice
\def\sett@b{\ifx\next\+ \let\next=\relax % turn off \outerness
    \def\next{\afterassignment\s@tt@b\let\next}%
  \else\let\next=\s@tcols\fi\next}

...

\outer\def\+{\tabalign}
```

1. `\let\+=\relax` is done before defining `\sett@b` in case `\+` would already be an `\outer` token (otherwise, the `\+` token in the replacement text of `\sett@b` would cause an error when `\sett@b` is defined).
2. When the `\ifx\next\+` test is true during normal usage of `\settabs` in the document, `\next` is an `\outer` token since in normal usage, `\+` is `\outer`. Thus, Knuth does `\let\next=\relax` before redefining `\next` with `\def\next{\afterassignment\s@tt@b\let\next}`, otherwise the `\next` token at the end of the replacement text in this definition would cause an error.

Comment: +1 I love the irony ...

Comment: Regarding “famous”? Well, these macros *are* famous for being the most difficult to understand in `plain.tex`. :)

Comment: no, just the fact that Knuth himself had to get rid of his own `\outer` definition due to the inconveniences coming along with it :D

Comment: Ah, that way. :-) (Security is almost always antagonist to convenience, you know... for some special TeXish definition of security here)

Answer (score 8):

For luatex, there is

```
\suppressoutererror = 1
```

which makes the entire issue go away.

You can use it globally or just locally in a group while you make the required definitions.

Answer (score 5):

[As already pointed out in egreg's answer:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533231/118714)

If  `\outer`-tokens are "hit" by `\noexpand`, they will be turned into `\relax` (only) for the next expansion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\outer\def\myoutermacro{My outer macro's definition.}

\def\FirstOfOne#1{#1}%

\newtoks\myscratchtoks

\begin{document}

% This does not work:
%
% \FirstOfOne{\myoutermacro}.
%
% These do work:

\expandafter\FirstOfOne\expandafter{\noexpand\myoutermacro}

\myscratchtoks\expandafter{\noexpand\myoutermacro}
\FirstOfOne{\the\myscratchtoks}

\edef\myscratchmacro{\noexpand\myoutermacro}
\FirstOfOne{\myscratchmacro}

\end{document}
```